# How can I remove/hide the Skype Status notification?

Tags: notifications, skype, 4.4-kitkat

Skype, like many applications, uses a persistent notification to keep from getting killed by the process manager. Usually, I would just hide this notification by going to the app's "App Info" screen and unchecking the "Show notifications" box. *However, I **want** to get message notifications.* Just not the constant "Available" notification.

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsZuL.png) of the notification I'm talking about.

After some Googling, I've found [people who suggest disabling the "Skype Status" notification](http://community.skype.com/t5/Android/Skype-4-0-Can-t-remove-permanent-notification/td-p/1726385) in the app settings. However, [that doesn't seem to be an option on my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqMsc.png).

I use Android 4.4 on a Nexus 5.

How can I remove/disable the Skype login/status persistent notification, without disabling other Skype notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible:

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12359/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-the-status-icon-in-skype-4-for-android-phones

Just tried it on my Nexus 7, works fine.

Comment: Well I'll be a monkey's uncle! I thought this question would never get revived. You, sir, deserve a [Necromancer badge](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer) for your fine answer.

Comment: I found the answer by accident, I was trying to do the opposite of what you described in your question!

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The default option now seems to be to hide that notification.

Comment: Apparently this does not work any more. Or rather: The icon is disabled by default. And the option to turn it on (as described in the answer) is not there any more. Suggestions where/how to enable it welcome.

Answer (score -2):

If it's not available from inside the app, you can always:

1. long touch the notification
2. touch "App Info"
3. Untick show notification
   this should do the trick.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I already considered this. However, I don't want to disable *all* Skype notifications. Thanks though!

Comment: sorry for not noticing. I don't of another solution then.